# Is “gaze de naval” English idiom, French idiom or a half-breed?

Tags: word-usage

I was drawn to the word,“gaze de navel” appearing in New York Time’s (July 6) article titled “Goodbye Old World, Bonjour Tristesse” written by Maureen Dowd).
http://www.nytimes.com/2013/07/07/opinion/sunday/dowd-goodbye-old-world-bonjour-tristesse.html?hp&_r=0

It goes:

> Joie de vivre has given way to **gaze de navel**. The French are so busy
>   wallowing in their existential estrangement — a state of mind Camus
>   described as “Should I kill myself, or have a cup of coffee?” — that
>   they don’t even have the energy to be rude. And now that they’re
>   smoking electronic cigarettes, their ennui doesn’t look as cool. It’s
>   not that they’ve lost faith in their own superiority. They’ve lost
>   faith that the rest of the world sees it.

Merriam-Webster online English Dictionary defines “navel gazing” as “useless or excessive self-contemplation.” Google Ngram shows that the usage of “navel gazing” emerged in / around 1960 and the currency is on a sharp rise. Neither registers 'gaze de navel.'

However, “gaze de naval” sounds to me foreign - somewhat half-breed (Pardon me if this is the misuse of word) of English and French words.

Does “gaze de naval” pass as a chic English idiom that I can try to use in conversation and in writing, or it is just Dowd’s special coinage?

Comment: "Dowd", not "Dawd". // Parenthetically - I've made a few 'nitpicky' comments on your posts. I've done so *because* you're clearly very good at English, and pursuing an even finer grasp of the language.   Sometimes the 'nits I pick' are ESL things (mistakes a NES would not make), other times - like here - just typos that could happen to anyone.   I can stop if it's annoying.   Keep up the questions; you ask a lot of good ones, and I especially enjoy when you provide Japanese counterparts, comparisons, etc.

Comment: Hunter2. Thanks for your pointing out a typo of Dowd. Actually I have a keen interest in English counterparts of Japanese idioms and proverbs, but I’ve restrained from asking such questions to the minimum (4 or 5 of total 600 questions I’ve posted), because I thought it’s not concerns of native English speakers at large. Your comment is encouraging. I may not feel so guilty every time for asking “too localized question.”

Comment: Well, I haven't followed you *that* closely, but I thought I saw a few of your Questions that were not asking for counterparts, but mentioned related words, concept, idioms, etc. You might be right - that some here might be strict about being 'On Topic'. *I* am interested in both - Questions that are clearly 'On' (to which you might add a Japanese-speaker's perspective), *and* Questions that are potentially 'Off'.   FWIW

Comment: Sort of a tangent, but ... https://www.xkcd.com/1120/  (Note the 'mouse-over text').

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maureen Dowd, as many of your questions show, has a penchant for neologisms, as do many other columnists. In this case, I believe she is drawing a parallel between the existing borrowed French expression *joie de vivre* and her own tongue-in-cheek *gaze de navel*. I don't believe this is an existing expression (as your searches showed), but rather using the *X de Y* construction to contrast navel-gazing with *joie de vivre*. A one-off coinage.

Comment: Avner, so "a one-off coinage" is an euphemism or "gaze de navel" is really a barbarism?

Comment: @Carlo: Yes, I think you're right. :^)

Comment: For an example of a genuine English expression using genuinely French words with correct grammar, see *nom de plume*, which has been used in English to mean a pen-name since the 19th century while the French would use the more general *nom de guerre* for all pseudonyms though they borrowed *nom de plume* back in the 20th century.

Answer (score 1):

As a certified Frenchman (with passport and all), I can certify that “gaze de navel” is not French at all. The only French word in the locution is "de" (which means 'of'). The locution appears to have been forged on a French pattern (like "aaaaa de bbbbb": "coup de foudre", "eau de toilette", "nom de plume", "tour de force"), but Maureen Dowd used English words to make it understandable by her primarily English-speaking readers. The current French translation of “gaze de navel” would be "nombrilisme" (literally, "navelism").

Comment: Well, it’s not true that _de_ is the only French word in the phrase—[_gaze_](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaze) is a perfectly fine French word, meaning ‘gauze’; and _navel_ is (as in English) [a kind of orange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navel_orange#Navel_oranges). Of course ‘navel orange gauze’ is not what Ms. Dowd was referring to in her fanciful coinage, but still. They are words in French. ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet *“Il y a des mots qui font vivre, et ce sont des mots innocents. . . .”* —Paul Eluard